# Subset df to adjust for timestamps

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I am trying to create a new `df` by accounting for timestamps. Specifically, for the `df` below, I begin by returning all rows where the `integer` in `Number` is `diff` from the previous row.

I then want to adjust these timestamps based on these two rules:

1. If integer in `Number` increases, round timestamp to previous 15min mark
2. If integer in `Number` decreases, keep the current timestamp

I'm not sure if this is the most efficient method but I'm currently undertaking this by subsetting two separate dataframes and then merging. I return all increases in number and amend the timestamp, while returning all decreases and remaining the same. When I merge these two is when I get into trouble.

If the gap between differences in integers is close then the rounding can cause the series to be incorrect. Essentially, `Number` is incorrect if there's an increased integer within 15min of a decreased integer. Because it's get's rounded, the resulting timestamp gets misplaced.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Time' : ['1/1/1900 8:00:00','1/1/1900 9:59:00','1/1/1900 10:10:00','1/1/1900 12:21:00','1/1/1900 12:26:00','1/1/1900 13:00:00','1/1/1900 13:26:00','1/1/1900 13:29:00','1/1/1900 14:20:00','1/1/1900 18:10:00'],                 
    'Number' : [1,1,2,2,3,2,1,2,1,1],                      
    })

# First and last entry in df. This ensures the start/end of the subsequent
# df includes rows where the 'Number' increases/decreases.
first_time = df.loc[0,'Time']
last_time = df.loc[df.index[-1], 'Time']

# Insert 0 prior to first race
df.loc[-1] = [first_time, 0]  
df.index = df.index + 1  
df.sort_index(inplace=True) 

# Insert 0 after the last race
df.loc[len(df)] = last_time, 0

# Convert to datetime. Include new column that rounds all timestamps. If timestamp
# is within 10mins of nearest 15min, round to that point.
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
df['New Time'] = df['Time'].sub(pd.Timedelta(11*60, 's')).dt.floor(freq='15T')

# Create separate df's. Inc contains all increased integers. Dec contains
# all decreases in integers  
df = df[df['Number'] != df['Number'].shift()]
Inc = df[df['Number'] > df['Number'].shift()]
Dec = df[df['Number'] < df['Number'].shift()]

del Inc['Time']
del Dec['New Time']
Inc.columns = ['Number','Time']

# Merge df's
df1 = pd.concat([Inc,Dec], sort = True)

# Sort so it's time ordered
df1['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Time'])
df1 = df1.iloc[pd.to_timedelta(df1['Time']).argsort()]
```

I've plotted a figure below to display how The `New Time` in the figure doesn't record when `Number` increases to `2` at `1:30:00` because of the new rounding.

**What I'm hoping to happen, is to disregard a decrease in integer if it falls between 15min of an increased integer.**

```
x = df['Time']
x2 = df1['Time']

y = df['Number']
y2 = df1['Number']

plt.plot(x,y, drawstyle='steps-mid', label = 'Old Time')
plt.plot(x2,y2, drawstyle='steps-mid', label = 'New Time')
plt.legend()
plt.xticks(rotation = 45)
```

[image]

Output:

```
    Number                Time
1        1 1900-01-01 07:45:00
3        2 1900-01-01 09:45:00
5        3 1900-01-01 12:15:00
6        2 1900-01-01 13:00:00
8        2 1900-01-01 13:15:00 *Was previously 13:29:00
7        1 1900-01-01 13:26:00 *To be removed because within 15 of previous row
9        1 1900-01-01 14:20:00
11       0 1900-01-01 18:10:00
```

Expected Output:

```
    Number                Time
1        1 1900-01-01 07:45:00
3        2 1900-01-01 09:45:00
5        3 1900-01-01 12:15:00
6        2 1900-01-01 13:00:00
8        2 1900-01-01 13:15:00
9        1 1900-01-01 14:20:00
11       0 1900-01-01 18:10:00
```

**Edit 2:**

I'm having trouble when there is increases in consecutive 15min timeslots. It seems to miss the first increase and just return the second increase.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Time' : ['1/1/1900 8:00:00','1/1/1900 9:49:00','1/1/1900 10:00:00','1/1/1900 10:13:00','1/1/1900 12:26:00','1/1/1900 13:00:00','1/1/1900 13:22:00','1/1/1900 13:45:00','1/1/1900 14:21:00','1/1/1900 14:36:00'],                 
    'Number' : [1,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,3,4],                      
    })

# if you Time column is not of type datetime64, please execute the following line:
df['Time']= df['Time'].astype('datetime64')

# add some auxillary columns
df['row_id']= df.index                                         # this is needed for the delete indexer to avoid deleting adjusted rows that are joined with itself
df['increase']= df['Number'] > df['Number'].shift(1).fillna(0) # this is to identify the rows where the value increases and fillna(0) makes sure the value of the first row is regarded as an increase if it is larger than 0
df['Adjusted Time']= df['Time'].where(~df['increase'], df['Time'].sub(pd.Timedelta(11*60, 's')).dt.floor('15min')) # the Adjusted Time is the time we want to display later and also forms a range to delete (we want to delete other records later, if they lie between "Adjusted Time" and "Time"

# merge the ranges to identify the rows, we need to delete
get_delete_ranges= df[df['Time'] > df['Adjusted Time']]        # those are the ranges, for which we have to look if there is something else inbetween
df_with_del_ranges= pd.merge_asof(df, get_delete_ranges, left_on='Time', right_on='Adjusted Time', tolerance=pd.Timedelta('15m'), suffixes=['', '_del'])

# create an indexer for the rows to delete
del_row= (df_with_del_ranges['row_id_del'] != df_with_del_ranges['row_id']) & (df_with_del_ranges['Time'] >= df_with_del_ranges['Adjusted Time_del']) & (df_with_del_ranges['Time'] <= df_with_del_ranges['Time_del'])

# delete the rows in the overlapping ranges
df_with_del_ranges.drop(df_with_del_ranges[del_row].index, axis='index', inplace=True)
# remove the auxillary columns and restore the originals column names
df_with_del_ranges.drop([col for col in df_with_del_ranges if col not in ['People', 'Adjusted Time']], axis='columns', inplace=True)
df_with_del_ranges.rename({'Adjusted Time': 'Time'}, axis='columns', inplace=True)
```

Out:

```
   Number                Time
0       1 1900-01-01 07:45:00
1       2 1900-01-01 09:30:00
2       2 1900-01-01 10:00:00
3       2 1900-01-01 10:13:00
4       1 1900-01-01 12:26:00
6       2 1900-01-01 13:00:00
7       2 1900-01-01 13:45:00
9       4 1900-01-01 14:15:00
```

Expected Output:

```
   Number                Time
0       1 1900-01-01 07:45:00
1       2 1900-01-01 09:30:00
2       2 1900-01-01 10:00:00
3       2 1900-01-01 10:13:00
4       1 1900-01-01 12:26:00
6       2 1900-01-01 13:00:00
7       2 1900-01-01 13:45:00
8       3 1900-01-01 14:00:00 #Index 8 in df has an increase at 14:21. Should be rounded up to 14:00 and Number should be 3
9       4 1900-01-01 14:15:00
```

Comment: Apologies. Fixed

Comment: I've included this @jezrael. Does the question make sense? It's a little hard to describe.

Comment: Hi, could you please add the input values, for which you gave the expected output?

Comment: Nice task. I liked it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following code:

```
# if you want the last time in your dataframe to be zero, just execute the following line (as this is equivalent to adding a new column and deleting the old one):
df.iloc[-1, 1]= 0

# if you Time column is not of type datetime64, please execute the following line:
df['Time']= df['Time'].astype('datetime64')

# add some auxillary columns
df['row_id']= df.index                                         # this is needed for the delete indexer to avoid deleting adjusted rows that are joined with itself
df['increase']= df['Number'] > df['Number'].shift(1).fillna(0) # this is to identify the rows where the value increases and fillna(0) makes sure the value of the first row is regarded as an increase if it is larger than 0
df['Adjusted Time']= df['Time'].where(~df['increase'], df['Time'].sub(pd.Timedelta(11*60, 's')).dt.floor('15min')) # the Adjusted Time is the time we want to display later and also forms a range to delete (we want to delete other records later, if they lie between "Adjusted Time" and "Time"

# merge the ranges to identify the rows, we need to delete
get_delete_ranges= df[df['Time'] > df['Adjusted Time']]        # those are the ranges, for which we have to look if there is something else inbetween
df_with_del_ranges= pd.merge_asof(df, get_delete_ranges, left_on='Time', right_on='Adjusted Time', tolerance=pd.Timedelta('15m'), suffixes=['', '_del'])

# create an indexer for the rows to delete
del_row= (df_with_del_ranges['row_id_del'] != df_with_del_ranges['row_id']) & (df_with_del_ranges['Time'] >= df_with_del_ranges['Adjusted Time_del']) & (df_with_del_ranges['Time'] <= df_with_del_ranges['Time_del'])

# delete the rows in the overlapping ranges
df_with_del_ranges.drop(df_with_del_ranges[del_row].index, axis='index', inplace=True)
# remove the auxillary columns and restore the originals column names
df_with_del_ranges.drop([col for col in df_with_del_ranges if col not in ['Number', 'Adjusted Time']], axis='columns', inplace=True)
df_with_del_ranges.rename({'Adjusted Time': 'Time'}, axis='columns', inplace=True)
```

This results in:

```
In [131]: df_with_del_ranges
Out[131]: 
   Number                Time
0       1 1900-01-01 07:45:00
2       2 1900-01-01 09:45:00
4       3 1900-01-01 12:15:00
5       2 1900-01-01 13:00:00
7       2 1900-01-01 13:15:00
8       1 1900-01-01 14:20:00
9       0 1900-01-01 18:10:00
```

Without the `.loc[-1, 1]=0` the `Number` column in the last row would contain 1.

Comment: Just recognized the 11 minute adjustment you apply in your code and updated my code accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a bunch @jottbe. This problem was consuming me for hours.

Comment: just a quick one. I've got an edge case where it's not returning increases that occur in consecutive 15 min timeslots. It's disregarding the first one increase and just returning the second increase. I've included a new edit showing this in the question.

Comment: Ok, I know, what happened. The last record from 14:36 was an increase from 3 to 4. So according to the rule, 11 minutes were subtracted and the result rounded to 14:15. In this case the rows inbetween 14:15 and 14:36 need to be adjusted (deleted). From my interpretation of the description this adjustment. It seems this interpretation was wrong. But to change this is not a big issue. You just need to change the `del_row` indexer and replace `'Time'` by `'Adjusted Time'` everywhere (on the left side of the inequality) while leaving the `'..._del'` fields as they are. Then you need one extra...

Comment: ...aggregation step, because the delete logic based on the `'Adjusted Time'` might produce rows with exactly the same `'Adjusted Time'` if two rows lie within a small time range both representing an increase and both rounded to the same time. I guess you wouldn't want to have two output lines for the same time in this case, right?

Comment: So the Aggregation would be on the `'Adjusted Time'`. Maybe you can clarify, what you would like in that case. Both records with the same time, or the max of them? and needs to be applied before the `del_row`-indexer is created on this aggregated dataframe. At the moment I am not at home and can't change it, because my possibilities are a bit limited here, but if you like I can fix it this way.

Comment: Sorry for the delay @ jottbe. Both records with the same time would be fine. I can adjust afterwards.